# Cscope output all parameters

Tags: function, parameters, call, definition, cscope

There is a limitation of 1 line per cscope entry, e.g.

```
type func(type param1, type param2,
          type param3, type param4)
```

will give

```
type func(type param1, type param2,
```

cscope entry.

I need cscope to output all parameters in function definitions and calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is achievable.
However, as a workaround you could use `grep`, which is more "flexible" and parse the output of:

`grep -Ri -A 2 "type func" .`

This would print the lines that contains `"type func"` and with `-A 2` the 2 following lines.
You can also use regex to get the output until the closing `)` of function declaration.

Comment: I need to output function callers and calls with all parameters, e.g.: caller_function1 function2_call(param1, param2)

Comment: That is why I said it is a workaround : you can assume roughly on how many lines the call would be, `grep` will output those lines, after that you would need an extra-process to check that you have all the parameters and output not beyond the end of the call `)`